# Twilio API: Transferring connection to a forwarded number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

Im placing an outbound call, and based on the automated message from whom Twilio is calling, it calls my phone with the connection.

Here is the script that places the phone call.

```py
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


account_sid = "xxxx"
auth_token = "xxxx"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create( url='http://myhost.com/rec.php',to='+1234',from_='+9876')

print(call.sid)
```

The phone call is placed, and the action script sends a TwiML gather response. Here's `rec.php`

```php
echo '<Response>
  <Gather input="speech"
        partialResultCallback="http://myhost.com/partial.php"
        action="http://myhost.com/finalresult.php">
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

I've got the partial page logging the text. But when I forward a call, my phone rings for one second, then disconnects. There's no errors in the debugger either.

Here's partial.php

```php
if(contains("To continue in English", $_REQUEST['UnstableSpeechResult'])){

    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
          <Response>
           <Dial>+myPhoneNumber</Dial>
          </Response>";
}
```

here is final result, which i think is called when the phone call is complete? im not sure.

```php
if(contains("To continue in English", $_POST['SpeechResult'])){
        echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
                <Response>
                        <Dial>+myPhoneNumber</Dial>
                </Response>";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [partialResultCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#partialresultcallback) doesn't process TwiML.

> The webhooks Twilio makes to your partialResultCallback are
> asynchronous. They do not accept any TwiML in response. If you want to
> take more actions based on this partial result, you need to use the
> REST API to modify the call.

Not sure how your phone is ringing given the above. Any more details you can provide will help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: i have updated the question with `finalresult.php`

Comment: The action URL is called when the speechTimeout/timeout expires. The default timeout is 5 seconds of nothing said, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#speechtimeout. Maybe the dialed party hangs up while your TwiML is executing (so it rings you once and they hangup which kills your call).

Comment: I don't personally. I haven't had the need to look.

Comment: that's my bad. My account was taken over. I'm back to Twilio.